# Google Api: How do I retrieve a Calendar's Private Address or Magic Cookie

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to retrieve the "Private Address" of a google calendar using the Google API.

The private address includes not only the calendar address, but also a [Magic Cookie](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#AuthMagicCookie) to allow access to a private calendar without authenticating.

From a browser, it is easy enough to open the calendar settings and copy the URL with the required Magic Cookie, but I am creating a large number of calendars for an organization and really need to be able to capture this information using the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like no luck for us http://markmail.org/message/fkqu62uyrmtfb3y4#query:+page:1+mid:4gymer5r4qn6qbdm+state:results

> The magic cookie is not exposed through the API for security reason,
>   it can only be retrieved from going directly into the Calendar UI.

Comment: This is my understanding as well. I ended up just brute forcing it, which was quite painful.

Comment: I manually opened up each calendar in the browser, went to the share screen and then copy/pasted the displayed URL. Nothing automated. Perhaps 'manually' was a better term than 'brute force'

Answer (score 0):

Construct the URL yourself programmatically:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/*userID*/private-*magicCookie*/basic
```

Comment: I guess I might not have been clear, but I don't know where in the API to get the magic cookie from? If I had the magic cookie I would be able to easily construct the url.